# Adding Input and Output to component selectors

Tags: angular, routes

I have three components, Homepage(simply a welcome page with a link to the the AllCustomers view), AllCustomers(a list of all the customers plus a few functional buttons) and AddEdit(a form where one can add/edit customers). The AddEdit component should show up on button click on the AllCustomers component. My questions is how do add the input and output functionalities which allows the components to interact into the application routes.

here is my app.component.html

```html
<router-outlet></router-outlet>


<all-customers #allCustomers (add)="input.addCustomersNow()" (edit)="input.editCustomerNow($event)"></all-customers>
<add-edit-customer #input (ok)="allCustomers.refresh()"></add-edit-customer>
```

I understand this is wrong and it doesn't quite work the way I want to, but let me try and explain my difficulty. How do I add for example:  "#allCustomers (add)="input.addCustomersNow()" (edit)="input.editCustomerNow($event)" this information to the my routes.

below is are my routes:

```html
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/homepage', pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: 'homepage', component: HomepageComponent },
    {
      path: 'allCustomers',
      component: AllCustomersComponent,
      children: [
        { path: 'addEdit', component: AddEditCustomerComponent }
      ]
     },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a state management for your app you can use ngrx or just use a service as a store for your state and inject it in the components you use , this willmake your application more robust and maintainable.

Comment: I can't quite figure this out, but there must be a simple solution. Its simply changing changing views! That is I click on Homepage to see the customer list (All Customers component) and have a few functionalities there which communicated with AddEdit component. I can do view changes with simple routes but I can't figure out how or where to pass on the input/output arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The best practise is  to implement Single responsibiity theory . so you have to isolate the function of `AddEditCustomerComponent`. Let me explain. You just pass id paramater to that component and when ever you want to add a new record pass -1. and when you want a edit you pass the unique id of that record to the component then get the data from component related to that id via a service and let user to update. this way you can implement the delete and view if some click in a row on AllCustomersComponent list

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: 'homepage', component: HomepageComponent },
{
    path: 'allCustomers',
    component: AllCustomersComponent,
    children: [
        { path: 'addEdit/:id', component: AddEditCustomerComponent }
    ]
},
{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/homepage',
    pathMatch: 'full'
},
{ path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
```

I've just change this line

```
{ path: **'addEdit/:id'**, component: AddEditCustomerComponent }
```

hope this will work for you